# In apache-camel, what method is used to control ftp "PUT" file behaviour when using ftp component

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

When I tried to put file to remote server through camel FTP component, I want to customize the PUT behavior to meet my requirement as I did for get file from remote server.

However, I cannot found which method is actually performing put file to remote through FTP component.

Answer (score 0):

Camel uses commons-net library as the FTP client. You can look at that project how you can use it yourself to write you own code to upload a file to a FTP server and do any commands before/after and whatnot.

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

Comment: I have use camel to make my code to upload my file to remote server. I am looking at the method that is actually use to upload the file to remote server because I need to make some post/pre put command setting.